# How to Access and read bucket information of shared bucket using jets3t API?

Tags: amazon-s3, shared, bucket, jets3t

Here is the explanation for my error. I have registered two User's A, B in Eucalyptus (open-source). I Created a bucket B1 using Jets3t API in User A's Account and granted Read Permission To user B (Using "CanonicalGrantee" Interface). While Listing Access Control List Using A's Credentials i got FULL_CONTROL for A and READ For B. But When I tried to access Bucket B1 information using B's Credentials I got this error

> Exception in thread "main" org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: The action listObjects cannot be performed with an invalid bucket: null
>       at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.listObjects(S3Service.java:1410)
>       at test.ObjectPermission.main(ObjectPermission.java:40)

problematic code is    `S3Bucket publicBucket =s3Service.getBucket("B1");`

Here  B1 is Bucket belongs User A.  in the above code s3service returns a null Values . I know that s3service only retrieves the information belongs which are created under B' Credential.

I don't know how to resolve this and to access shared bucket using Jets3t API

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is search the bucket B1 of account A in the list of bucket of Account B. So always it does not found that bucket in the Account B and return null.
So you have to check it in another way. You can check it by doing head request for Bucket B1 for Account B Service object for that call isBucketAccessible() if it returns true thats means bucket is accessible else not.

I am 100% sure it will work :)

Comment: i have tried  isBucketAccessible() method from User B's S3Service Connection. I got false value as return, which means not Accessible

Comment: **" for Granting  Permission to User B  "**

`S3Service s3Service=new RestS3Service(cred1,"",null,jets3); //s3service given A credentials `
`S3Bucket publicBucket =s3Service.getBucket("B1");`
`AccessControlList bucketAcl = s3Service.getBucketAcl(publicBucket);`
`bucketAcl.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee("kKPtnjKyqvTGHEEOuSVCYRnhqdxT1Chq3pmoCQ"), Permission.PERMISSION_READ);`
`publicBucket.setAcl(bucketAcl);`
`s3Service.putBucketAcl(publicBucket);`

Comment: when i list out ACL of Bucket B1 FULL_CONTROL for User A and READ permission for User B. 

Then I tried method s3Service.isBucketAccessible("B1") from User B. I don't why this method returning false even though User B has Permission to Read.